# Get users twitter id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

Can anyone tell me if there are any fields in the FB Graph that list a users twitter ID if they've linked it to Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no place in a Facebook profile to provide that information, and no way to retrieve it either - you'd have to get your user to log in to both Facebook and Twitter using their respective APIs